# Codeigniter get_where query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
public function countTasks(){
    $q = $this->db->get_where('tasks', array('task_status' => 1));
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

This is the function I have in my model that counts all rows in my 'tasks' table where the column 'task_status' is equal to 1. It basically returns an integer that I use for my pagination. The query is not working as it doesn't return any data even though I know I have 4 rows that match that requirement in my table.

I was gonna use the returned value for my pagination. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
return $q->num_rows();
```

Or

```
$this->db->where('task_status', '1');
$query = $this->db->get('tasks');

return $query->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->count_all_results();` is not working after the get function, so do this instead:

```
public function countTasks(){
    $q = $this->db->get_where('tasks', array('task_status' => 1));
    return return $q->num_rows();
}
```